# [JAVA]Wrong parameter of path on MAC OS for FileInputStream

Tags: java, macos, io, path, fileinputstream

As title, here's my code:

```
public class TestBufferIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte b[]=new byte[1];

        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("//Users//kiah//Desktop//1.jpg");
    }
}
```

but the path parameter will cause `FileNotFoundException` and that's the part I don't understand because I've taken care the escape characters and MacOS path format, the path comes from OS directly and the accessing qualification is available to all system users, moreover of course I'm sure the file exists and works, but it still fails.

Comment: "will cause compilation error". What error? I assume this is Java? Which version?

Comment: @Rob Napier Yes it's in JAVA, it will cause `FileNotFoundException`, I've edited my post, Thanks!

Comment: JDK version is 1.8 (8.0). Thanks!

Comment: Guys, sry for the rookie question, but I really don't know which part went wrong in the topic@@ Plz help me & I'll truly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Why are you doubling all the slashes? That's not useful. In C it would likely be silently ignored, but it's possible it confuses Java.

Comment: doubled it bcuz that slashes in JAVA equal escape characters, need to use double slashes to tell compiler it's `/`
Moreover I've tried to use single slash but still the same result.

Comment: Backslashes (\) are escape characters, not forward slashes (/). I have no idea why you get a file not found. I expect the file isn't really there. You can test with "ls /Users/kiah/Desktop/1.jpg" but beyond that there's nothing here to go on.

Comment: @Rob Napier thx for reminder, and do u mean enter "ls /Users/kiah/Desktop/1.jpg" into mac commander?If so then I've done it but it just responded the path again.

Comment: sign...so many ppl writing code in mac os & I can't get any help of this...dunno why...OTZ

Comment: @RobNapier do u know where my prob is? thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it's because the method didn't handle checked exception.